# Django allauth Microsoft SSO

Tags: django, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, django-allauth

I'm having trouble configuring my SSO options for my Django project that I'm working on.  I'm hoping to make it so that only those users in my organization are able to sign into the application but I keep getting the following error:

> AADSTS50194: Application 'Azure: Application (client) ID'(DjangoAppSSO) is not configured as a multi-tenant application. Usage of the /common endpoint is not supported for such applications created after '10/15/2018'. Use a tenant-specific endpoint or configure the application to be multi-tenant.

I have gone in and populated the admin console with my Client ID being the same as above from the Azure account.  I also created a Client Secret with my Value and Secret ID and put those in the admin console as well.  I populated the Value as the "Key" in admin and Secret ID as the "Secret Key".  All the required imports are done for settings.py and I believe the issue is in what I am giving the SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS possibly.

settings.py:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'microsoft': {
       
        'APP': {
            'tenant': 'organization',
            'client_id': 'Azure: Application (client) ID',
        }
    }
}
```

Just for clarification sake, anywhere it says "Azure: Application (client) ID" is the actual value from there, I just don't want to post it anywhere.

Comment: are you developing a single-tenant app?

Comment: Trying to, I'd like to keep it just to people in my organization and not open it to the public.

Comment: It seems that the library Django allauth you are using supports multi-tenant azure ad app, not single-tenant azure ad app.

Comment: This answer may help for those struggling with single-tenant app / allauth integrations on Azure AD:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73885989/django-allauth-azure-ad-configurations/74199245#74199245

Answer (score 3):

> AADSTS50194: Application is not configured as a multitenant application. Usage of the `/common` endpoint is not supported for such applications created after '10/15/2018'. Use a tenant-specific endpoint or configure the application to be multi-tenant.

The above error usually occurs if users tried to sign-in to your single-tenant application with **multi-tenant** (**`/common`**) endpoint.

Please **note** that, **`organizations`** is used for multi-tenant applications where it allows users to sign in with both work and school accounts.

To **resolve** the error, you need to modify your **`settings.py`** file by replacing ***organizations*** with your ***Tenant ID*** like below:

```py
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'microsoft': {
       
        'APP': {
            'tenant': 'Your_TenantID', //You can also give tenant domain here(contoso.onmicrosoft.com)
            'client_id': 'Azure: Application (client) ID',
        }
    }
}
```

You can find **`Tenant ID`** of your tenant like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your Application -> Overview***

[image]

**Alternatively**, you can change your existing single tenant application to **multi-tenant** by changing its Supported account types without modifying **`settings.py`** like below:

[image]

**Reference:**

[Client application configuration (MSAL)  | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration#how-to-specify-the-audience-in-your-codeconfiguration)

[Microsoft OAuth2 provider for django-allauth by Vincent Schänzer](https://github.com/schaenzer/django-allauth-microsoft)

Answer (score 0):

I have just posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75684841/21363485) answer to a similar topic. You now need to use 'TENANT' capitalised or it will not work