# django-allauth Azure Ad Configurations

Tags: django, azure, django-allauth

I'm tyring to setup django azure ad authentication using django-allauth but currently the documentations is not having proper documentation for setting up Azure ad.

I have client_id, secret and tenant_id with me. I have tried few configurations but it seems to be not working.
Config 1:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'azure': {
        'APP': {
            'client_id': 'client_id',
            'secret': 'secret',
            'key': ''
        }
    }
}
```

Config 2:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'azure': {
        'APP': {
            'client_id': 'client_id',
            'secret': 'secret',
            'key': '',
            'tenant_id': '',
        }
    }
}
```

```
I have experimented few more configuration but its seems to be not working
https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html
```

Comment: Could you try changing 'azure' to **'microsoft'** under `SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS` in settings.py file? Refer [this](https://github.com/schaenzer/django-allauth-microsoft)

Comment: yes... but i  have found the new settings, i think its not documented there    'azure': {
        'TENANT': '',
        'APP': {
            'client_id': '',
            'secret': '',
            'key': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>'
        }
    },

Answer (score 3):

As you say, the documentation is lacking on this integration.  I was able to get Azure SSO working with the following configuration in settings for a ***single tenant*** app.  First, make sure you have all of the following declared in `INSTALLED APPS`:

```
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.microsoft",
```

Note the absence of `.azure` as a provider.  My tests revealed that using `.microsoft` as the provider worked with my registered **single tenant** applications in Azure AD, where `.azure` did not, and would throw an error upon sign in.  You did not specify whether your app is single or multi-tenant.

Secondly, declare your configuration as follows:

```
    SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
        'microsoft': {
                'tenant': secrets.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID, 
                'client_id': secrets.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
        }
    }
```

`secrets.` is just my custom secret manager, the important part is the syntax and the IDs you pass.  The 'tenant' here is not your subscription tenant ID, but the tenant ID that is displayed in the Overview blade of your registered application in Azure AD.  The `client_id` is in the same Overview area, just above "Object ID" as of this writing. Note the absence of `APP: {}` above.  This threw me at first too. I picked up a clue from [this GitHub post](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/2911).

Finally, to get this to work, you must create a "Social Application" record in django-allauth's admin panel inside the Django Admin.  Give the app whatever name you want, and add both the 'Client ID' and the 'Application Secret' here from the Azure AD Registered Application.

Answer (score 3):

I currently had the need to add authentication against Microsoft Azure and used  django-allauth (v0.57) and also found the documentation lacking and ran into issues with setting it up properly.

Hopefully this wi ll help others the frustration I had :-)

I was able to solve them with the following steps:

Add the following to settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    # The following apps are required:
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    ...
    # Required for django-allauth
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount",
    # Provider(s) for django-allauth
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.microsoft",
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    # dlango-allauth middleware
    "allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware",
    ...
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    ...
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by email
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
    ...
]

# Specify the context processors as follows:
TEMPLATES = [
    ...
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                # Already defined Django-related contexts here

                # `allauth` needs this from django
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
            ],
        },
    },
    ...
]
```

I created an application in Microsoft Azure portal at https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade

[image]

1. Enter a name of your liking
2. Choose desired application access
3. Make sure to configure the proper redirect url for the web application, e.g. http://localhost:8000/accounts/microsoft/login/callback/.

I also created a secret for this application.

[image]

***Make sure to document the value of the secret as it will not be shown in full after creation.***

I did not configure any other settings in settings.py and chose to add the configuration in the database through the admin pages (but you could also add it into settings.py using the `SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS` dictionary as well I guess) by creating a new Social Application in the admin interface of your django application under http(s)://.../admin/socialaccount/socialapp/add/:

[image]

1. Choose: `Microsoft Graph`
2. Set a name of your liking
3. Enter `Application (client) ID` as shown on the overview of your application
4. Enter `Client Secret Value` as shown when creating the secret
5. Enter `Client Secret ID` as shown when creating the secret
6. Keep default (`{}`) if you have configured your application for multi-tenant authentication (default) or in case of single tenant change to (make sure to use lowercase in this case for the tenant key in the JSON fragment):

```
{
    "tenant": "organizations"
}
```

EDIT: Fix order of Client Secret Value and Client Secret ID as pointed out by @muaz-shahid

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find a fix for it, when you create a new client secret, it provides the user with a Client Secret ID and a Client Secret Value, the value should be used for the secret key while you register your app on the Django admin panel.

Adding to Jonathan's answer above, the Client Secret's Value needs to go in the Secret Key row in the admin panel.

Comment: Isn't that already detailed in step 4 and 5 of the 'Add Social App' part of my instructions?

Comment: Your answer should mentions that the Client Secret's Value should go in the "Key" field but that did not work when I tested it, instead of that the "Client Secret's Value should go in the "Secret Key" field in the admin panel.

Comment: Finally got around to testing it, you are right. I fixed the post. Thanks for pointing out the flaw.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to give an update on Milo's answer. After some frustrated attempts of this not working, I checked in the release notes of the [github project](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/release-notes.html) for django-allauth and noticed this comment on the 0.49.0 release:

> The Microsoft tenant setting must now be specified using uppercase TENANT.

Simply changing the case of 'tenant' to 'TENANT' will make this work